# Accessing Project Online Data Read/Write through CSOM / REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-server, ms-project, oauth, project

Hello I am trying to access data (for example tasks and the timesheet) saved in a Sharepoint hosted Project Online enviroment.
I would like to write a MVC app which is able to access the data in Project Online for a user which should login with his Office365 account. My problem is there is this **ProjectContext** class which is giving me all the power, but the user has to give me the credentials and it is not using this kind of fancy oauth login or some other ways, so i can not and i won't use this because also Two-way-auth is not working with this solution.

Another idea was to register a App in the Azure Active Directory which for sure works but i can not grand the app the permission to access Project Online.

For me it would also be fine to grab all the data via the REST interface but even there i need a way to authenticate and i do not want to save a password somewhere but indeed wan't a user to login through a login.microsoft.com where the user should give me the right to access it's project online data.

What is the solution to access the data?
Thank you in advance.